# XAML: Property on DependecyObject not updating when it is an item in an attached collection

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I have a DependencyObject that's inside an attached dependency property (that's a collection). Binding to that object does not work for some reason.

In my example, I am binding two things, a basic attached property (`local:CollHolder.BasicProperty`) and a regular dependent property (`local:MyItem.MyData`) - both are bound to the `Text` of a `TextBox` control.
The XAML looks like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <StackPanel x:Name="stack" local:CollHolder.BasicProperty="{Binding ElementName=text, Path=Text}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBox Text="" x:Name="text"/>
                <local:CollHolder.Coll>
                    <local:MyItem MyData="{Binding ElementName=text, Path=Text}"/>
                </local:CollHolder.Coll>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When changes happen the `Text` property, they propagate to the attached property, but not to the dependency property.

CollHolder:

```
public class CollHolder : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BasicPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BasicProperty", typeof(string), typeof(CollHolder), new PropertyMetadata("", DPC));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CollProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Coll", typeof(Coll), typeof(CollHolder), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public static Coll GetColl(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        var coll = (Coll)obj.GetValue(CollProperty);
        if (coll == null)
        {
            obj.SetValue(CollProperty, coll = new Coll());
        }

        return coll;
    }

    public static void SetColl(DependencyObject obj, Coll value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CollProperty, value);
    }


    public static string GetBasicProperty(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(BasicPropertyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBasicProperty(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BasicPropertyProperty, value);
    }


    private static void DPC(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Basic Property changed");
    }
}
```

MyItem:

```
public class MyItem : DependencyObject
{
    public string MyData
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyDataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyData.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyData", typeof(string), typeof(MyItem), new PropertyMetadata("", DPC));



    private static void DPC(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("CHANGED!!");
    }
}
```

And the collection is pretty simple:

```
public class Coll : List<MyItem>
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When changes happen the Text property, they propagate to the attached property, but not to the dependency property.

```
<TextBox Text="" x:Name="text"/>
<local:CollHolder.Coll>
  <local:MyItem MyData="{Binding ElementName=text, Path=Text}"/>
</local:CollHolder.Coll>
```

The `TextBox` and `local:MyItem` in the same `DataContext`, you could use `{x:Bind }` to get the text value directly.

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind }" x:Name="text" />
<local:CollHolder.Coll>
    <local:MyItem  MyData="{x:Bind }" />
</local:CollHolder.Coll>
```

**Update**

I tried to replace `MyItem` with `Control` to test whether `DependencyProperty` works in `Binding` mode. It works as expected. So, you could use `Control` as MyItem's base class.

```
public class MyItem : Control
 {
     public string MyData
     {
         get { return (string)GetValue(MyDataProperty); }
         set { SetValue(MyDataProperty, value); }
     }

     // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyData.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
     public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDataProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("MyData", typeof(string), typeof(MyItem), new PropertyMetadata("", DPC));

     private static void DPC(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine("CHANGED!!");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Cant use x:Bind - my real situation is actually where the binding needs to happen in an DataTemplate. I can't use x:Bind to the attached property in there, because I need it to be on an element.

Comment: Marking as answer, though inheriting from Control seems very heavy handed memory wise...